# How to immediately refresh ol.source.TileWMS

Tags: openlayers

How can I immediately update or refresh or redraw the ol.source.TileWMS ?

Answer (score 2):

Use updateParams on the source with a random parameter value.

> layer.getSource().updateParams({‘ol3_salt’: Math.random()})

Comment: does not work for me on ol 3.16